# How to import module (or reload if previously imported)

Tags: python, import, module, python-3.4

I have a module `my_module.py` containing:

```
var = 9
```

This module is dynamically imported and modified:

```
import importlib

def f(name):
    mod = importlib.import_module(name)
    importlib.reload(mod)
    return mod

print(f(name='my_module').var)  # Prints 9

# Changes var to 912
with open('my_module.py', 'a+') as opened:
    opened.write('12')

print(f(name='my_module').var)  # Prints 912
```

My `f()` function returns a module object after ensuring it is reloaded.

It works, but i m wondering if there is a **better way** to ensure that the module object returned is always reloaded.

Comment: You can normally rely on the fact that it will always reload. Otherwise, that code looks fine.

Comment: Given that `importlib.reload` *also* returns the module, that could be `return importlib.reload(importlib.import_module(name))`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know, but i think with a function it is much more readable.

Comment: Do you have any criteria for *"better"*? Is there something about the current implementation that specifically troubles you?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Speed mostly. Unnecessary reloads can increase time by 50% to 100% with a module i tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could calc&verify a hash on the file before reloading via hashlib, or just use the modification-date as an indicator if the lib has changed.
Alternatively, you could send a signal after modification with the signal-handler doing the actual reload.
The later might be the most efficient as the lib is really just reloaded if changed. It could even be combined with the hash to ensure it has actually been modified.